# Creating a complicated MySQL Update Query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to create an `UPDATE` query that will replace the `NameID` field on a table called `TimeStamps` with the user's `id` field value from another table called `Names`. Here is some sample data.

Names Table

```
id:1
name:John
password:1234
```

TimeStamps Table

```
id:1
name:**John**
timestamp:01/01/2000 12:00:00
```

I want to replace the `Name` field in the `TimeStamps` table with the corresponding `id` value from the `Names` table. I'm not entirely sure on how to write the query but I know it starts with something like this.

```
UPDATE TimeStamps
    SET NameID=(NamesTableReference)
    WHERE NameID=(TimeStampsTableReference);
```

This way I can start to run queries against the user's `id` and not the user's `Name`. We have more than one user with the same name and it doesn't pull the right data because it is pulling multiple users. I can update the data manually but there are several hundred thousand rows in the table and that would take entirely too much time. Can anyone shed some light on what I need to add/change in the query below? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a `join`:

```
update timestamps t join
       names n
       on t.id = n.id
    set t.name = n.name;
```

However, the `update` shouldn't be necessary.  You have an `id` connecting the two tables.  Just use it when you are using `timestamps`.  That is, use a `join` to look up the `name` rather than storing it in both places -- and running the risk that the names associated with an `id` somehow end up different in the two tables.

Comment: I tried running the query below and I think it has worked. Looking at the query, do you think the query should have accomplished what i was looking to do? I made a backup of the database before executing the query.   

UPDATE `TimeStamps` t, `Names` n SET t.`NameID`=n.`id` WHERE t.`NameID`=n.`Name`

Comment: @CharlesVincent . . . It looks to me like the ids and names are mixed up, but it is hard to say without example data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this query did the trick.

```
UPDATE TimeStamps t, Names n
SET t.NameID = n.id
WHERE t.NameID = n.Name
```

Thanks everyone for your input and your help! Hope this can help someone else in the future!